# How to get the Height of the VideoView included in the Activity

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I need to get the Height of the VideoView of my activity in android, I am using the following commands, but it gives me the Height as 0.

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video1);
String surl="SOME_LINK.mp4";
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(surl);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        vv.setVideoURI(uri);
        vv.setMediaController(mc);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(vv);
        mc.setAnchorView(vv);
        int vvHeight=vv.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.d("VideoView Height:",vvHeight+""); // The Logcat output : 0.
        int VVheight=vv.getHeight();
        Log.d("The Height of VideoView is :",VVheight+""); // The Logcat output : 0
```

Can Someone tell me what I am making an mistake.

Comment: Pravinsingh Waghela, where are you calling these methods ? In onCreate ?

Comment: @2Dee Yes in onCreate(). Its my Activity and not Fragment.

Comment: Please kindly review my answer. Calling getHeight will not work properly in onCreate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to get width/height before the view has been drawn.

Try this:

```
vv.post(new Runnable() { 
@Override
  public void run() {
    // get height and width here
  }
});
```

`view.post(Runnable)` causes the runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable will run on the UI thread.

Comment: I voted your answers up for suggesting the Runnable option and being able to justify this choice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested code this code at my end. Just Before onCreate() ends. just write these lines.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.e("",""+videoView.getHeight()+" "+videoView.getWidth());
            }
        });
```

If you have any query please let me know.

Comment: Runnable run on UI thread not on another thread. Yes. I always use this at my end and this is a tested code.

Comment: This is correct, but it's sad you could not explain *why* it works, like arol_123 did.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `getWidth` and `getHeight` in `onCreate`, but you cannot be sure the `View` is fully created and as a consequence, those methods will return 0. 
As an alternative, you can use a `ViewTreeObserver` :

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video1);
ViewTreeObserver vto = vv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Use getHeight here
        ViewTreeObserver obs = vv.getViewTreeObserver();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }

});
```

Alternatively, you can post a `Runnable` on your View. It will be put at the end of the queue of the UI thread, so when it is run, the layout has been measured, and `getHeight` returns the correct measurement.

```
vv.post(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Use getHeight here
    }
});
```

Comment: Now, why you edited your answer. You just copy paste other answwer. can you explain?

Comment: Yes, I can, what do you need explanation for ? I investigated the Runnable option to see *why* it was working, something that you didn't do even if you were suggesting that solution. I saw it was indeed a working solution and added that to my answer to provide the most complete answer possible.

Comment: I just want to say. Others has already give the solution on runnable. then you edit after seeing there solutions.

Comment: At least I understand what I'm doing, which is more than you can say. U mad ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code also check this [link](http://mrbool.com/how-to-play-video-formats-in-android-using-videoview/28299) for calculating the convenient dimensions

DisplayMetrics dm; //Declare

//Update this line code

```
dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int height = dm.heightPixels;
int width = dm.widthPixels;
```

//try this line code too

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(uriString);
mp.prepare();
int width = mp.getVideoWidth();
int height = mp.getVideoHeight();
```

NOTE: If you use android:layout_width:match_parent and `android:layout_height:match_parent to fill all screen width and height and to avoid video stretching and to maintain the aspect ration you should use a video with dimensions ratio 16:9

You need to run in view.post(Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video1);

ViewTreeObserver vto = vv.getViewTreeObserver();

vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
 public boolean onPreDraw() {
     vv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
     finalHeight = vv.getMeasuredHeight();
     finalWidth = vv.getMeasuredWidth();
     Log.d("debug" , "" + "Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
     return true;
                  }
                   });
```